# How can I show line numbers relative to the current one in Vim?

Tags: vim

Can I have this feature in Vim 7.3?

```
3    blah
2    blah
1    hello
512  current line
1    blah
2    blah
3    blah
```

The line numbers would be shown relative to the current one, which is shown in absolute numbers.

Answer (score 5):

This has been implemented in patch 7.3.787; just update your Vim to a recent version (a new 7.4 release is imminent, too), and you're good to go!

The latest source code and runtime files can be downloaded via FTP or retrieved from Mercurial; see [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/sources.php) for details.

Comment: Actually, 'relativenumber' has existed since "stock" 7.3. Patchlevel 787 is just a fix to show the absolute line number for the line the cursor is on when 'relativenumber' is enabled.

Comment: @Heptite ... and the question is about that absolute current line number; the example output in the question shows that the OP knows about the relativenumber feature.

Comment: My mistake, then.

Answer (score 3):

The `relativenumber` setting exists in Vim 7.3.

See `:help 'relativenumber'` inside vim or view it at [VimDoc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27relativenumber%27).

http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2012/relative-line-numbers-in-vim-for-super-fast-movement/ discusses ways to use it in more detail. (It was the top Google result for "vim relative line numbers".)